# Permission denied trying to execute a jar file packaged by Maven with included dependencies on a user account

Tags: java, maven, serial-port, pom.xml, user-permissions

Plot Summary:

I'm working on a Maven application (in VS Code) which uses `com.fazecast.jSerialComm`. I have set up another user account on the same machine which I want to be able to run it. I set up pom.xml to build a jar file  and include the necessary dependencies, and packaged it up.

This is all happening on Ubuntu 19.04, by the way, and also it's my first project using Maven.

Testing the resulting file out in my own account and home folder, it seems to work fine (no matter where I put it)... However, when I copy it to the user account I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/jSerialComm/1568526835050-libjSerialComm.so (Permission denied)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
        at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.<clinit>(SerialPort.java:227)
        at main.java.app.GcodeSender.initSerialCommunication(GcodeSender.java:81)
        at main.java.app.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:96)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.openPortNative()'
        at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.openPortNative(Native Method)
        at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:430)
        at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:450)
        at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:463)
        at main.java.app.GcodeSender.initSerialCommunication(GcodeSender.java:90)
        at main.java.app.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:96)
```

Here is what I've done when copying the file to the other account's home folder:

1. Copied it with `sudo cp`
2. I made that user the owner of the file with `chown`
3. I gave the file read and execute permissions for all users with `chmod`
4. I added the user account to the `dialout` group, because the application uses `jSerialComm` to talk over a USB cable.
5. I switched to the user account, and tried to run the file with `java -jar <path to file>`

Here is where I configure my pom.xml to package up my dependencies etc:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        <mainClass>main.java.app.DrawingApp</mainClass>
      </manifest>
      <manifestEntries>
        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>main.java.app.DrawingApp</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

I interpret this as the other user account not having permission to access the `jSerialComm`, even though it is built in to the jar file which the user is the owner of and has `rx` permissions for.

Am I packaging it wrong in Maven?

Thank you for your help!